# Pasar arreglo por partes en PHP

Tags: php, array

Quiero insertar o no cierto bloque de codigo(otro arreglo) dentro de un arreglo en **PHP**
este *arreglo* si funciona

```
$miarreglo=array('media_gallery_entries' =>
           array(
                'media_type' => 'image',
                'types' => array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'),
                'content' => array('type' => $ext1,'base64_encoded_data' => $dataimg,'name' => 'nombre imagen')
                ),
            array(
                'media_type' => 'image',
                'types' => array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'),
                'content' => array('type' => $ext2,'base64_encoded_data' => $dataimg2,'name' => 'nombre imagen'))
        ));
```

pero estos pequeños bloques de codigo los puedo poner o no dependiendo el contenido de las variables

```
    array(
                'media_type' => 'image',
                'types' => array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'),
                'content' => array('type' => $ext3,'base64_encoded_data' => $dataimg3,'name' => 'nombre imagen')
            )
```

Intente guardando el bloque de codigo en una variable algo asi

```
if($ext1==''){
 $arregloimagen1='';
}else{
 $arregloimagen1=array(
    'media_type' => 'image',
    'types' => array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'),
    'content' => array('type' => $ext1,'base64_encoded_data' => $dataimg,'name' => 'nombre imagen')
    );
    }
```

asi mismo con los demás bloques(3), e insertandolos al arreglo original :

```
$miarreglo=array('media_gallery_entries' => array(  
        $arregloimagen1.','.$arregloimagen2
        )
    );
```

pero al utilizar mi arreglo no me lo marca como formato no valido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo necesitas agregar el nuevo arreglo como elemento de 'media_gallery_entries', puedes usar [`array_push($arrayActual, $nuevoElemento)`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) o simplemente con `$arrayActual[] = $nuevoElemento`:

```
$miarreglo=array('media_gallery_entries' =>
           array(
                'media_type' => 'image',
                'types' => array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'),
                'content' => array('type' => $ext1,'base64_encoded_data' => $dataimg,'name' => 'nombre imagen')
                ),
            array(
                'media_type' => 'image',
                'types' => array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'),
                'content' => array('type' => $ext2,'base64_encoded_data' => $dataimg2,'name' => 'nombre imagen'))
        ));


$arreglo2 = array(
                'media_type' => 'image',
                'types' => array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'),
                'content' => array('type' => $ext3,'base64_encoded_data' => $dataimg3,'name' => 'nombre imagen')
            );
// Solo necesitas agregarlo como un elemento más de 'media_gallery_entries'
$miareglo['media_gallery_entries'][] = $arreglo2;
```

Comment: En todo caso media_gallery_entries tabien pertenece a otro arreglo, seria lo mimo con array_push????$arrayProducto =  array(
   'sku'               => 'sku',
   'name'              => 'nombre',
   'visibility'        => 4,
   'type_id'           => 'simple',
   'media_gallery_entries' => array(

   )
   );